# workbook.createSheet() method not recognized in IDE using apache POI

Tags: java, apache, apache-poi

I am trying to learn apache poi but the method workbook.createSheet() seems to be not recognized by the IDE. reviewing the suggestions that are there, many methods are available for the workbook object but not the createSheet method.

```
Workbook wb = Workbook.createWorkbook((List<Record>) response.getOutputStream());
Sheet s = wb.createSheet(); <<-- not working for me.
```

my import statements look like this and I have no idea what is the problem. maybe i need some snooze.

```
import org.apache.*;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.model.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.model.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.record.Record;
```

edit:

the library that I am using, I just downloaded it and I added it as an external library in eclipse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering the amount of time that which I don't have lots, and the comparison between the functionalities between the two APIs, I'll just use JXL for now.

Answer (score 3):

You're importing the wrong classes!

`org.apache.poi.hssf.model.*` should only be used for low level handling. The classes you want are under `org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel`. In there you'll find the correct [createSheet method](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Workbook.html#createSheet%28%29)

If you follow the [Apache POI examples](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#NewSheet) you'll end up with something like:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;

Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.open(new File("myfile.xls")); // or .xlsx
Sheet s = wb.createSheet();

// Add some more data, then save
```

Answer (score 0):

As per this [doc](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Workbook.html#createSheet%28%29) you should be importing

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
```

Comment: I did that and eclipse marked it with a red tag, suggesting that unused imports be removed. the wb.createSheet() still acts the same even with the new import

Comment: Did you remove the old one too?

Comment: yes I did, but it still came up with errors. anyway, I'll just be using JXL just to get the job done